# When are new tensorflow releases uploaded to piwheels.org?

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I used the latest version of Tensorflow (1.12) on my PC to create a custom model using tf.keras and when I load it on the Raspberry Pi (using Tensorflow 1.11) it throws an error.

The code I ran was:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('filename.hdf5')
```

And the error was:

```
ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform
```

Apparently, when you pip install Tensorflow on a Raspberry Pi it uses piwheels.org for the package instead of pypi.org. The latest version on piwheels.org is 1.11 instead of the current Tensorflow version 1.12. I assume the error is caused by a Tensorflow version incompatibility.

I am wondering when are new Tensorflow releases added to piwheels.org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow wheels for Raspberry Pi are uploaded to piwheels.org shortly after release, but it's not 100% automated so it can sometimes takes a few emails between Google and Raspberry Pi to sort it out. Sorry! :)